# Is Tower of Brahma mentioned in any Hindu text?

Tags: brahma, mathematics

[Tower of Brahma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi), is a *mathematical* puzzle which describes the concept of *recursion*. Does this originate in a *Hindu* text? If yes, please also mention the original text of the puzzle.

Wikipedia describes the fable thus without giving any references:

> There is a story about an Indian temple in *Kashi Vishwanath* which
>   contains a large room with three time-worn posts in it surrounded by
>   64 golden disks. *Brahmin* priests, acting out the command of an ancient
>   prophecy, have been moving these disks, in accordance with the
>   immutable rules of the Brahma, since that time. The puzzle is
>   therefore also known as the *Tower of Brahma* puzzle. According to the
>   legend, when the last move of the puzzle will be completed, the world
>   will end.

Comment: You can add info of Kasi Vishwanath temple story  and you can ask for that legend references in Hindu Scriptures.

Comment: Okay done. Btw, did you close-vote and down-vote?

Comment: Nope. Didn't use neither of them. If you had provided this story before, you could have averted downvote and close vote. People generally tend to downvote question, if they feel question doesn't show good research. Now, it looks actually on topic and they may feel it is story about Kasi Vishwanath temple and Brahma. Voted to reopen after reading wiki page.

Comment: Hmm, well, it is not really research, just copy-paste from the link I already mentioned. Although, your point is well-received. :)

Comment: People don't really feel this question belongs to Hinduism until and unless they know this story. So, copy-paste doesn't matter when reference is provided.

Comment: Gotcha :) .....